# Find the remainder when the sum is divided by $1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Find $S \pmod{1000}$ given: $$S = \sum_{n=0}^{2015} n! + n^3 - n^2 + n - 1$$

$$S_0 = 0! + 0  - 0 + 0 -1 = 0$$
$$S_1 = 1! + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 1$$
$$S_2 = 2! + 8 - 4 + 2 - 1 = 7$$

This isn't helping, so:

$n! = n(n-1)(n-2)...(1)$ but that is too complicated.

The $n!$ term is the hardest one. Besides that:

$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{2015} n! + \frac{2015^2 2016^2}{4} - \frac{(2015)(2016)(4031)}{6} + \frac{2015(2016)}{2} - 2015$$

$$\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{2015} n! + 25(4) - 15(336)(31) + 15(8) - 15 \pmod{1000}$$

**Please offer hints, thank you!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT :

Since $1000=2^3\cdot 5^3$, note that
$$15!\equiv 0\pmod{1000}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2015}n!\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\color{red}{14}}n!\pmod{1000}$$

Comment: We can reduce the sum further down to 12 terms, since $14!+13! = (14+1)13!$

Comment: @SBareS: That's a nice idea.

Comment: @mathlove, thanks. But still, computing $14! + 13! + 12! + 11! + ... $ isnt easy to calculate

Comment: @Amad27: Note that we don't need to calculate, for example, $12!$. What we need is $12!\pmod{1000}$. As SBareS pointed out, since we have $13!+14!\equiv 0\pmod{1000}$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{2015}n!\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{12}n!\equiv 1+1+2+6+24+120+720+40+320+880+800+800+600$. I hope this helps. Here, I used $7!=5040\equiv 40\pmod{1000},8!\equiv 40\times 8\equiv 320\pmod{1000}$, and so on.